# To open on-screen keyboard from my Python code on macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, on-screen-keyboard

```
open -a KeyboardViewer
```

I found that it's possible to launch on screen keyboard via the above terminal command.

I am trying to open the OSK from my python code. How can I launch it ( osX)

Comment: Please don't SHOUT.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling an external command from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-from-python)

Comment: I found that   " os.system("osk")  ""  will launch the virtual keyboard in windows....?anything like this available for Mac OS

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
cmd = 'open -a KeyboardViewer'
os.system(cmd)
```

the above code will simply launch the virtual keyboard.